# checking user permissions in replicated salesforce database

Tags: api, permissions

For integration purposes I am regularly dumping/updating the full Salesforce database to our on-premise system. To do that, I am using a Salesforce admin user with all privileges (so that we can fetch all object and items).

How can we replicate the user permissions for on-premise use? Certain users are only allowed to acccess specific account on the Salesforce plattform, and we would like to be able to check their permissions on the on-premise database dump as well.

Is there a way to regularly dump the permissions table or call a Salesforce API in real-time ("e.g. to check if user #1 can access item #33 in object "accounts").

Comment: I know it's bit rude to vote to close (and when the title looks completely off) but the accepted answer will match I believe and it's pretty straightforward. Check also http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/record_access_uth/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood.pdf for some more theory behind it all.

Comment: hello, thanks for the comment and the linked answer is indeed  the right way to go. With "close", do you mean delete?

Comment: No, the question will stay here as a header. That way future visitors who will have similar problem will have greater chance of finding that answer. It takes 5 votes to "close as duplicate" but then a nice link shows up. Don't worry, you haven't done anything wrong. Especially that you wouldn't find easily that answer to which I have linked without knowing what to search for :)